# Handle CCAvenue response in angular js 2.0

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using angular js 2.0 as client side application which communicate with ASP.Net core to performer server calls. I am using ccavenue seamless integration kit where i am generating encrypted request using server call which contains "www.abc.com/success" as success URL. After clicking on buy button on www.abc.com site is redirecting to CCAvenue.com and perform transaction,After successful transaction from CCAvenue ,Site is redirecting to provided success URL(www.abc.com/success) where are getting "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used." error.

I am confused how to handle HTTP post response from CCAvenue in angular 2.0 application.

Comment: do u have a registered route for `www.abc.com/success` ? is this inside the angular context ?

Comment: Yes when we hit www.abc.com/sucess from browser its opening page but request comes from ccaveune response call its giving above error.

Comment: let me write down what i understood:
-user is somewhere in abc.com 
-user clicks buy
-user is redirected to external application: everything that happens there is in a 3rd party app and on success user is redirected back to the webiste abc.com/success 


correct ? 
where are you trying that this.http.post ? which url and which component ? can u also please provide some code snippets of the http req

Comment: Yes user redirect to payment gateway site, Correct their party site response back to abc.com/success which is http response with post method, now in angular my abc.com/success is route which need to handle this post method which is not working. or i dont know how to handle this case

Comment: `their party site response back to abc.com/success which is http response with post method` <- i think this is the problem you need to handle this server-side. I have no experience in .NET but i think you have to create a route in the server with .post (if the website is sending a POST to /success) and handle the request there. and then attache a .get in the /success route so angular can "ask" what happened. i am just doing a guess to be honest - but if you pay for that provider if i were you i would contact them for more details

Comment: Thanks DrNio Yes i need to handle it from server side its not possible from client side

Comment: great to help - posted a more general answer for future reference as comments are not very visible for most users, u can upvote it if u want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After publishing its plain HTML and at the end once you come to main site HTML cant identify routing mechanism. You need to implement some server-side page like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As we mentioned in the comments there is no angular way or 'client-side' way to fix this. Should be handled in the backend with .post and .get routes for the status of the payment.